# How to delete a specific folder in specific folders

Tags: bash

Using

```
find . -name "*_develop-*"
```

I am able to find all folders in the current directory that contain `_develop-` in the folder name, e.g.

```
myfolder_develop-abcd  
myfolder_develop-efgh
```

Now inside these found folders I'd like to delete the folder "temp".
How do I pipe the required command to look into the resulting folders, find the required folder and then delete it?

Comment: You can always filter with grep, and result pass with xargs to rm -rf command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-exec` option to make a `rm -rf` command on match folder.

Command should be like that :

```
find . -name "*_develop-" -exec rm -rf  {}/tmp/ \;
```

`{}` represent a match folder, so `{}/tmp/` represent tmp folder inside a match folder

Comment: temp is a folder inside the develop folder, not part of the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use -regex flag

```
find . -regex '.*_develop-.*/temp' -type d -delete
```

or if it is the folder directly below

```
find . -regex '.*_develop-[^/]*/temp' -type d -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find with xargs

```
find . -wholename "*_develop-*/temp" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Using `print0` and `xargs -0` replace spaces by a `NULL` character. It is useful if there is spaces in some directory names, so xargs would fail without it.

You could use find `. -wholename "*_develop-*/temp" -delete` but that will fail if `temp` directory is not empty.